# how to show messages according to time sent by user using javascript

Tags: javascript, time, message

I want show time under message as 1 min and 2 min etc. Time should be calculated according to the message arrival. Now I'm having this format `4:33:08 AM` and I want to calculate it according to message arrival and display it like  Examples `1min` `4min` `25min`, I just wanted in that format. Help me finding the solution.

[image]

```js
var today = new Date();
var time = today.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = time;
```

```css
 color: white;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        background-color: #343a40;
        line-height: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        font-size: 15px;
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: @nurdyguy you've mistaken. I want to show time under message div according to the message arrival.

Answer (score 0):

For this need it's the best to use library like moment.js
https://momentjs.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javascript only, but you can use [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) for do it easily.

Here is a example:

```
var time1 = moment();
var time2 = moment().add(10,'minutes')

time2.diff(time1,'minutes') // 10
time1.diff(time2,'minutes') // -10
```

You can see more in https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Also, if you don't want to add momentJS, a good alternative to moment is: [Date FNS](https://date-fns.org/).

And after you get the result, you just need to put inside the div.